# Adding Color to button after cloning

Tags: unity

```
public GameObject button;

public void Start()
{
       GameObject button1 = Instantiate(button) as GameObject;
       button1.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
       button1.transform.position = new Vector3(7, 0, 2);
}
```

I have cloned the button game object now want to add color to that game object how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [retrieve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) the [Button component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) and apply the [new color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) to the [target graphic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-targetGraphic.html).

```
public void Start()
{
   GameObject button1 = Instantiate(button) as GameObject;
   button1.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
   button1.transform.position = new Vector3(7, 0, 2);
   UnityEngine.UI.Button buttonComponent = button1.GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
   buttonComponent.targetGraphic.color = new Color32(r,g,b);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks does the same hold for 3d components like sphere ?

Comment: Nihal you should learn the basics of how components work and what type of components there are.

Comment: @NihalSaxena : In order to change the color of a simple sphere, you have to call `GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = ....`